# PostgreSQL GROUP BY: SELECT column on MAX of another WHERE a third column = x

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

Let's suppose we have two tables in PostgreSQL:

Table "citizens"

```
country_ref   citizen_name    entry_date
-----------------------------------------------------
0             peter           2013-01-14 21:00:00.000
1             fernando        2013-01-14 20:00:00.000
0             robert          2013-01-14 19:00:00.000
3             albert          2013-01-14 18:00:00.000
2             esther          2013-01-14 17:00:00.000
1             juan            2013-01-14 16:00:00.000
3             egbert          2013-01-14 15:00:00.000
1             francisco       2013-01-14 14:00:00.000
3             adolph          2013-01-14 13:00:00.000
2             emilie          2013-01-14 12:00:00.000
2             jacques         2013-01-14 11:00:00.000
0             david           2013-01-14 10:00:00.000
```

Table "countries"

```
country_id     country_name   country_group
-------------------------------------------
0              england        0
1              spain          0 
2              france         1
3              germany        1
```

Now I want to obtain the last entered citizen on the "citizens" table for each country of a given country_group.

My best try so far is this query (Let's call it Query_1) :

```
SELECT country_ref, MAX(entry_date) FROM citizens 
LEFT JOIN countries ON country_id = country_ref 
WHERE country_group = 1 GROUP BY country_ref
```

Output:

```
country_ref   max
---------------------------------
3             2013-01-14 18:00:00
2             2013-01-14 17:00:00
```

So then I could do:

```
SELECT citizen_name FROM citizens WHERE (country_ref, entry_date) IN (Query_1)
```

... which will give me the output I'm looking for: `albert` and `esther`.

But I'd prefer to achieve this in a *single query*. I wonder if it's possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should be simplest and fastest:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (i.country_ref)
       i.citizen_name
FROM   citizens  i
JOIN   countries o ON o.country_id = i.country_ref
WHERE  o.country_group = 1
ORDER  BY i.country_ref, i.entry_date DESC
```

You can easily return more columns from both tables by simply adding them to the `SELECT` list.
[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/851fc/1)

Details, links and explanation in this related answer:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT citizen_name, 
       country_ref, 
       entry_date
from (
  SELECT cit.citizen_name, 
         cit.country_ref, 
         MAX(cit.entry_date) over (partition by cit.country_ref) as max_date,
         cit.entry_date
  FROM citizens cit
    LEFT JOIN countries cou ON cou.country_id = cit.country_ref 
  WHERE cou.country_group = 1 
) t
where max_date = entry_date
```

SQLFiddle demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/50776/1

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you simply:

```
SELECT citizen_name FROM citizens WHERE (country_ref, entry_date) IN (
    SELECT country_ref, MAX(entry_date) FROM citizens 
    LEFT JOIN countries ON country_id = country_ref 
    WHERE country_group = 1 GROUP BY country_ref
)
```

It might not be the best plan, but it depends on many factors, and it is simple to write.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm actually doing so far (see that I wrote SELECT citizen_name FROM citizens WHERE (country_ref, entry_date) IN (Query_1) in my question) but I would like to do it in a single query if possible...

Comment: @Francisco: that **is** a single query

Comment: Sorry about that, I meant to say I'm trying to avoid nested queries or the use or subqueries.

Comment: Why? There is no logical reason to avoid them.

Comment: I was thinking that my first query was complex enough to then be used inside another query.